# PowerShell Issue

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

```
get-eventlog -LogName system -ComputerName servername | where {$_.source -eq "user32"} | select -first 1 | Format-List
```

The above command does not return back to the prompt after displaying the desired result.

This happens only in the case of remote computers. If I use "localhost" it works just fine.

Comment: Worked fine here as well. BTW you can specify source as a parameter to Get-EventLog e.g. `-Source User32`.

Comment: I am doing it on powershell 2.0. Can that be the reason ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are running into is that Select-Object can kill the pipeline locally in PSv3, but it can't do that remotely.  So you continue to get results until it is finished.  Since your conditions mean that you will filter out all but one result, it seems like it is hanging.

Try removing the Select-Object (and maybe the Where-Object) to see how long it takes to run normally.  You should also do more filtering in the remote call itself rather than filter after receiving the data.

```
Get-EventLog -LogName system -Source "user32" | select -first 1 | Format-List
```

Comment: Actually its works. Takes some time but comes back to the prompt. Thanks!!